# I have no method Image.FromStream

Tags: c#, bitmap, zebra-printers

I'm converting a data type `byte[]` image using this method:

```
using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream (sign.ToArray ()))
{
    bmp = new Bitmap (s)
}
```

When I try to print the image it does not print the image as such but as a character string.

I'm using a Zebra sales ticket printer with the following code:

```
_printer.GetGraphicsUtil();
PrintImage(bitmap, x, y, width, height, insideFormat);
```

The printout looks like this:

[image]

The table where I keep a blob type that does not weigh too much on the database and get and keep using a component RESCO

```
inkBox1.Save(ms, Resco.Controls.OutlookControls.InkBox.BitmapType.Bmp1, false);
```

Why don't I get the correct printout?

Comment: I don't quite get your issue. According to the title, you're missing the method `Image.FromStream` but according to your statements, you are having a runtime issue, like the image is not showing somewhere.

Comment: My understanding is that Zebra printers use ZPL print instructions not .bmp images. Chances are you are mixing the bytes from one or the other and so the data yu are sending to the printer is not the data it is expecting.

Comment: Thanks the problem was with the printing method of zebra device is a flag that was to be placed in false which is to insideFormat well and I get the image of the firm.


PrintImage (bitmap, x, y, width, height, insideFormat);